# Is there a way to automatically split large clusters that are greater than some maximum number of points?

Tags: python, clustering, geospatial, dbscan

I ran HDBSCAN on these coordinates and got some clusters but some are too large. HDBSCAN has a minimum cluster size parameter, but no maximum size. All I want is to intuitively divide larger clusters so that none are larger than a maximum cluster size. Essentially, something that creates the second plot below. I could rerun HDBSCAN on the cluster, but it isn't guaranteed to reduce the size. I can do k-means, but I'm using clustering on a shortest-path distance matrix, something that I don't think k-means can handle.

[image]

````cl
df = pd.concat([cl.geometry.x, cl.geometry.y], axis = 1)

mins = 40
min_size = 400

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=min_size, min_samples=mins, allow_single_cluster=True) 
clusterer.fit(df.iloc[:, 0:2])
pd.Series(clusterer.labels_).value_counts()

df['cluster'] = clusterer.labels_
df['subcluster'] = np.nan

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

unique_labels = np.unique(clusterer.labels_)
noise_data = df[df['cluster'] == -1]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,6)) # Create 1 row, 2 columns of plots

for label in unique_labels:
    subset = df[df['cluster'] == label]
    if label == -1:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label="Noise", color='gray', marker=".", alpha=0.3)
    else:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label=f'Cluster {label}', marker = ".", alpha=1)

ax[0].set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax[0].set_title('Clusters')
ax[0].legend()```
````

Comment: From the image above, it seems like HDBSCAN is doing a great job (may be confirmed with some performance metrics). Without understanding why you need to do such a thing, you could try running a second clustering algorithm over the already formed and big clusters.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a max cluster size parameter for HDBSCAN.

What I would suggest is trying to work with the other parameters. For example tweaking `min_samples` or `cluster_selection_epsilon` might help you get smaller clusters. I'd try to use small `min_samples` and very small `min_cluster_size` to try and get the algorithm to work on the micro-scale. The parameters are explained very nicely here: https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html

Another approach might be utilizing the hierarchy of clusters created by HDBSCAN. Based on a cluster size threshold, you could then use the condensed tree object and use the children of the big cluster, instead of itself. You can read more about the condensed tree here:
https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_hdbscan.html

Finally, as you've already mentioned, you can have a heuristic cutoff threshold and run secondary clustering on the bigger initial clusters.